# Problems with updating Listbox

Tags: asp.net, sql, listbox

Hey there i got a asp.net solution where i got 1 dropdownlist (filled with packages from sql)
and 1 listbox (filled with software from sql) and 1 last witch should show software linked to a selected package from the dropdownlist.

the last listbox is filled with a datasource from sql when the page load.

my problem is. when i select a package in the dropdownlist i want the last listbox to update. and again when i select a software from the softwarelistbox and hit the add button, i want the last listbox to update when new data...

how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you're not an expert in ASP.NET, and for that **I will give you an easy answer**:

Give [ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Default.aspx) a go, and check the [**Cascading DropDown**](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) as I'm sure that's what you want.

Comment: i have just checked out that Cascading Dropdown.. can it be used in same way to fill a listbox depending on what is selected in the dropdown ?

Comment: sure it can, it's exactly the same thing :)